# 'CreateEvent': is not a member of '`global namespace'' in ASIO

Tags: c++, namespaces, visual-studio-2015, boost-asio, openframeworks

I'm working on a project that includes ASIO.  I added the library and header files, but when I have a file that includes `asio.hpp`, I get the following errors:

```
1>c:\users\me\documents\of_v0.9.1_vs_release\addons\ofxasio\libs\asio-1.10.6\include\asio/detail/config.hpp(229): warning C4005: 'ASIO_ERROR_CATEGORY_NOEXCEPT': macro redefinition (compiling source file src\ofApp.cpp)
1>  c:\users\me\documents\of_v0.9.1_vs_release\addons\ofxasio\libs\asio-1.10.6\include\asio/detail/config.hpp(215): note: see previous definition of 'ASIO_ERROR_CATEGORY_NOEXCEPT' (compiling source file src\ofApp.cpp)
1>c:\users\me\documents\of_v0.9.1_vs_release\addons\ofxasio\libs\asio-1.10.6\include\asio/detail/impl/win_thread.ipp(59): error C2039: 'CreateEvent': is not a member of '`global namespace'' (compiling source file src\ofApp.cpp)
1>c:\users\me\documents\of_v0.9.1_vs_release\addons\ofxasio\libs\asio-1.10.6\include\asio/detail/impl/win_thread.ipp(59): error C3861: 'CreateEvent': identifier not found (compiling source file src\ofApp.cpp)
1>c:\users\me\documents\of_v0.9.1_vs_release\addons\ofxasio\libs\asio-1.10.6\include\asio/detail/impl/win_thread.ipp(69): error C2039: 'CreateEvent': is not a member of '`global namespace'' (compiling source file src\ofApp.cpp)
1>c:\users\me\documents\of_v0.9.1_vs_release\addons\ofxasio\libs\asio-1.10.6\include\asio/detail/impl/win_thread.ipp(69): error C3861: 'CreateEvent': identifier not found (compiling source file src\ofApp.cpp)
1>c:\users\me\documents\of_v0.9.1_vs_release\addons\ofxasio\libs\asio-1.10.6\include\asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_handle_service.ipp(42): error C2039: 'CreateEvent': is not a member of '`global namespace'' (compiling source file src\ofApp.cpp)
1>c:\users\me\documents\of_v0.9.1_vs_release\addons\ofxasio\libs\asio-1.10.6\include\asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_handle_service.ipp(42): error C3861: 'CreateEvent': identifier not found (compiling source file src\ofApp.cpp)
```

Research online suggests that this is possibly due to me needing to redefine `_WIN32_WINNT` to the proper version number; however, I've tried a few versions numbers and either get an `incompatible version of Windows error` or no resolution to the above error.

I also found documentation on the Windows Dev site:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and I saw that it requires `WinBase.h` for older versions of Windows, and `Synchapi.h` for Windows 8.  I'm running Windows 8.1; but unfortunately including neither of these options worked.

Does anyone have suggestions for what might be causing this error?

The entire source for the project is here: https://github.com/morphogencc/ofxAsio/tree/master/example-udpreceiver

Comment: Try `#include <windows.h>` as the first line of your `.cpp` file. Forget about  ẁinbase.h` or `synchapi.h`, you, as a user, are expected to just include `windows.h`... most of the time.

Comment: Possibly progress -- if I include it in my `.cpp` file, I get an `error C1189: WinSock.h has already been included`.  Hmm..

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same compiler problem on a project that was using boost and Poco.  Turns out that Poco includes a "UnWindows.h" file which undefines a lot of windows macros.  To prevent Poco from undefining the macros, I added POCO_NO_UNWINDOWS to my list of pre-processor definitions.  That seems to have resolved the boost issue.

Answer (score 2):

While compiling boost websocket application, I got "CreateEvent: is not a member of 'global namespace' in ASIO" error. When I compile the individual files everything worked fine except the main application file where I combine all headers. I changed my order of header files by adding the boost headers on top. It solved the problem. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Changing the order of the header files (putting <boost/application.hpp> on top) fixed the problem for me as well.